# How to remove the extra blank line in algorithm2e

Tags: line-breaking, algorithm2e

I want to add a right aligned comment in LaTeX after `\For` command, but it adds an undesired blank line. Please help me.

CODE:

```
\For(\tcp*[r]{Incremental calculation of edges}){$i \gets 1$ \textbf{\upshape{to}} $n$}{
\If {$i=1$}
{
$currentCenter \gets MEAN(x_{R'[2]},\ldots,x_{R'[k_{min}+1]})$\;
$currentSSE \gets SSE(x_{R'[2]},\ldots,x_{R'[k_{min}+1]})$\;
}}
```

SNAPSHOT:

[image]

Comment: please provide a minimal compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`  there is not enough context in your question to give a definitive answer.  please also identify what version of `algorithm2e` is being used -- a recent instance of a very similar situation required code changes because an older version of the package was being used (the current version is 5.0 2013/01/06); it was possible to determine the needed changes from the package documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `\tcp*[f]` rather than `\tcp*[r]`. According to the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) documentation (section **10.3 comments**, p 31):

> `\tcp*[r]` right justified side comment, ends the line (default)
>
> `\tcp*[f]` right justified comment, without end line; useful with "if-then-else" macros for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\newcommand{\variable}{\textup}
\newcommand{\func}{\textsf}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\For(\tcp*[r]{Incremental calculation of edges}){$i \gets 1$ \textbf{\upshape{to}} $n$}{
  \If {$i=1$}
  {
    $currentCenter \gets MEAN(x_{R'[2]},\ldots,x_{R'[k_{min}+1]})$\;
    $currentSSE \gets SSE(x_{R'[2]},\ldots,x_{R'[k_{min}+1]})$\;
  }}
\For(\tcp*[f]{Incremental calculation of edges}){$i \gets 1$ \textbf{\upshape{to}} $n$}{
  \If {$i=1$}
  {
    $\variable{currentCenter} \gets \func{MEAN}(x_{R'[2]},\ldots,x_{R'[k_{\min}+1]})$\;
    $\variable{currentSSE} \gets \func{SSE}(x_{R'[2]},\ldots,x_{R'[k_{\min}+1]})$\;
  }}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I've added some other formatting as well, since it seems needed.

Comment: Thank you really. Do publisher really use such complex formatting when publishing a real article or book, or they use a specialized tool? That's really a hard work!

Comment: @remo: That's what they use, or perhaps [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings), which can auto-format the output. However, I do it that way when working with pseudo-code, and the use of macros for formatting is to promote [consistency](http://goo.gl/792Wc).

Comment: Is it a limitation that the `[f]` option doesn't exist for `\tcp` (not right justified)? There is unfortunately no way to apply your solution for `\tcp` instead of `\tcp*`

Comment: @jmon12: Use `\tcp*[h]`. See section **10.3 Comments** in the [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithm2e).

Comment: Ah yes OK thanks! I've been confused with the role of `*` in `\tcp*` since I thought it was the "right justified" version of `\tcp`. So the logic is that `\tcp*` can take options (with default `[r]`), and `\tcp` cannot.